# Inserting names on invitations, two per page in specific locations

Tags: datatool, textpos

I am doing a wedding invitation and I want the RSVP to have the person's name on it.  I also need the name to appear in another, very specific location on the invitation.  The invitation only takes up half of a page so I'd like to do two per page.  So, I need the second person's name to appear in two different, very specific locations on the page.  Then the next page should have the third and fourth people and so on.  I have used the textpos package to place figures on the entire invitation and have attempted to get the datatool package to place the names from a .txt file but I have had no luck.  Any ideas?  This is my insufficient work thus far.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloadrawdb{database}{Database.txt}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{database}{\name=Name}{
\begin{textblock*}{1in}(1in,1in)
\name 
\end{textblock*}
}

\DTLforeach{database}{\name=Name}{
\begin{textblock*}{1in}(2in,1in)
\name 
\end{textblock*}
}

\DTLforeach{database}{\name=Name}{
\begin{textblock*}{1in}(2in,2in)
\name 
\end{textblock*}
}

\DTLforeach{database}{\name=Name}{
\begin{textblock*}{1in}(1in,2in)
\name 
\end{textblock*}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? Working from what you already have set up is likely to produce a better solution for you; and people will be more inclined to help out. :-)

Comment: Ok, so I can make it place names.  I built a text file in csv format with one column called "Name".  I added the entries Bob and John.  The only thing I can get to work to place names is the simplest possible thing, but that places both names on top of each other.  I guess I don't know the datatool package too well.  If I try to insert page breaks it doesn't work.  I want Bob on the 1 inch line and John on the 2 inch line.  Then I want it to page break and add say Steve and Cindy.  I'll follow with the MWE that clearly isn't doing it.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloadrawdb{database}{Database.txt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{PlaceOnPage}

\DTLforeach{database}{\name=Name}{
    \begin{textblock*}{1in}(1in,1in)
        \name 
    \end{textblock*}
    \begin{textblock*}{1in}(2in,1in)
        \name 
    \end{textblock*}
    \ifcase\value{PlaceOnPage}\relax
        \textblockorigin{0pt}{0.5\paperheight}
        \stepcounter{PlaceOnPage}
    \or
        \null\clearpage
        \textblockorigin{0pt}{0pt}
        \setcounter{PlaceOnPage}{0}
    \fi
}

\end{document}
```

To have more than two names on each page, you can expand the `\ifcase`-construct to like below, and perhaps add `\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}` to the preamble.

```
\ifcase\value{PlaceOnPage}\relax
    \textblockorigin{0pt}{0.5\paperheight}
    \stepcounter{PlaceOnPage}
\or
    \textblockorigin{0.5\paperwidth}{0pt}
    \stepcounter{PlaceOnPage}
\or
    \textblockorigin{0.5\paperwidth}{0.5\paperheight}
    \stepcounter{PlaceOnPage}
\or
    \null\clearpage
    \textblockorigin{0pt}{0pt}
    \setcounter{PlaceOnPage}{0}
\fi
```

Comment: So I ran this and it generated the first name, Bob, four times.  I want something that will generate Bob only on the top lines, then the next name.  I then want it to page break and generate the third and fourth names, then on the next page the fifth and sixth.

Comment: I've edited the answer, does it produce the desired result now?

Comment: Just for curiosity's sake.  How would you make it do four different names per page?

Comment: See updated answer :)